# How is the ERC721TokenReceiver.onERC721Received data parameter used in practice?

Tags: erc-721, nft, erc-1155

The [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) and [ERC-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) NFT standards’ `safeTransferFrom` functions both accept a `bytes data` parameter which is then passed on unaltered to the transfer recipient address if this is a smart contract.

- Are there token-receiver contracts in the wild that are using this `data`?
- Are there any popular wallet implementations that actually let the user specify this `data` when transferring an NFT? (or specify it themselves under the hood?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original thought was this would be used mainly for passing a price to a marketplace contract.

Everyone using it (just a few people) are using it for that.

I don't know of any wallets that support arbitrary data.

In my experience, wallets are VERY slow to add features, so it might come some day.

Comment: I see! Any open source code you know of that you could kindly point me to? Thanks for your reply, and for the standard of course.

Comment: But would a marketplace typically be the receiver of a token, or rather the token’s approved address or the operator of the token’s owner?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, nowadays, marketplaces are basically all using "setApprovalForAll". Much like using "curl example.com | sh" to install software, I am surprised people do this.

Comment: Here is a receive function that uses data: https://github.com/sz-piotr/eth-card-game/blob/master/src/ethereum/contracts/ERC721Market.sol#L20-L31

Comment: Could only find a few others that do anything in the callback: https://github.com/venanetwork/prajna/blob/master/contracts/test/mocks/MockERC721Receiver.sol#L48

https://github.com/vaporgraph/aragon-apps/blob/master/apps/vault/contracts/connectors/ERC721Connector.sol#L34

https://github.com/androolloyd/safe-nft/blob/master/packages/hardhat/contracts/SafeNFT.sol#L63-L66

Comment: I was deep scrolling. Here is my query in case you're interested https://github.com/search?p=4&q=data+%22function+onERC721Received%22+-%22bytes+memory%29+public%22+-%22bytes+public%22+-interface+-mock+-test+-0.4.24&type=Code

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply.

setApprovalForAll: I agree. It’s a bit similar to approving infinite allowance in ERC-20.

eth-card-game: Nice. Seller sends token to the marketplace with attached price tag, buyer sends exact amount of ETH to marketplace indicating token. I always thought of this buy/sell logic as being included in the NFT contract itself, but of course implementing it in the marketplace like this makes sense because it can be made to work with any ERC-721 contract that is already deployed.

Comment: The eth-card-game example is the best, because the others are mocks (just recording the passed `data`), or it is not clear how they are using `data`. TBH I had forgotten that you can code-search Github (though it would be nice if it supported regular expressions.) I hope I can manage to unearth some further interesting usages too, thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/MrClottom/crispy.finance-contracts/blob/main/contracts/products/market/TokenVault.sol#L56)’s one example that packs two values into `data`. So it could be said that in general, `data` holds the “transfer metadata” (in a format specified by the receiver.) So if the token is being transferred to a marketplace for the purpose of being sold, `data` might not only be the price, but might also include further metadata relating to the sale, e.g. sale type (e.g. sale, auction) and associated parameters (e.g. reserve price, expiry, etc.)

Comment: Going back to my original question about wallets, it would be certainly more interesting for wallets if the `data` format were governed by some standard. Then if enough marketplaces implemented this standard, it would be possible for a wallet to have e.g. a generic “Sell” button.

Comment: My opinion is that entrepreneurs should spend the capital and reputation to go and make something popular **first**. Then later, they should go ask other people to follow them by writing a standard. // We are very far from a marketplace standard. And wallets wouldn't support it anyway because they don't get paid.