# How to split a string in solidity?

Tags: string, slice

I'm using the OpenZeppelin Preset of the 1155 Token Standard. (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/presets)
I'm able to mint tokens with that and I'm able to transfer 4 arguments with the transaction:

address (of the receiver)
id (of the Token)
amount (amount of Tokens)
data (additional data in bytes format)

I use the id and data for transmitting data
Now I'm confronted with the issue, that I want to transfer two variables (in string format) in the data field.
First of all I have to convert the field data from bytes into string.
Then I want to split the content of the data field into two variables.
The one variable got 13 characters, the other one 15.
Then I pobably have to assign each split to these two variables.
With emit Event I transfer both variables on the blockchain and can access it in the Logs.

Please pardon, I'm a bloody noob in coding with solidity.
Does someone knows how i can formulate a function that converts bytes to string, split the string into two parts and then assign it to new variables?

Comment: See Nick Johnson's [solidity-stringutils](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is yourself who is packing those two strings `s1` and `s2` into one `bytes`, then you may:

1. At the source ([in JavaScript](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder-encode)):

   `const data = abiCoder.encode(["string", "string"], [s1, s2])`
2. Pass `data` via the contract function
3. At the receiving end ([in Solidity](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions)):

   `(string memory s1, string memory s2) = abi.decode(data, (string, string))`

Doing it this way avoids string operations altogether.

P.S. Keep in mind that `data` is not intended for consumption by the `transfer` function itself, [but it is intended](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98779/how-is-the-erc721tokenreceiver-onerc721received-data-parameter-used-in-practice) for consumption by the *receipient* of the transfer (if that recipient is a compliant `ERC1155TokenReceiver` contract.)