# How to differentiate between ERC1155 fungible token transfers and non fungible token transfers

Tags: nft, events, erc-1155, transfer

I am new to erc-1155. I am trying to track erc-1155 NFT transfers and mints by suscribing to the TrasferSingle and TransferBatch events. However I am not sure how to differentiate between fungible token transfers and non fungible from these events, can someone please advice me?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc1155)'s example (down below) demonstrates things quite well (although, to be fair, most ERC-1155 tutorials or write ups don't make it obvious).

Both tokens minted by an ERC-1155 will leverage the same `_mint` function, which has the following function signature (we'll ignore the `_mintBatch` for simplicity sake, as the ensuing explanation should make it clear):

```
function _mint(address to, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In order to distinguish between the two, the *amount* dictates how to interpret which type of token is created. A *fungible* token has an amount **greater than 1**; a *non-fungible* token has an amount **equal to 1**.

If we take a look at the `TransferSingle` event, the `value` parameter represents the `amount` of tokens minted from `_mint`:

```
event TransferSingle(address indexed operator, address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 id, uint256 value);
                                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Let's take a look at the aforementioned example. You'll notice all of the tokens being minted have a significant supply (`10**18`, `10**27`, etc.), *except* for `THORS_HAMMER`. This token has an amount of `1`, meaning, it's an NFT. When this specific token gets minted, it'll emit a `TransferSingle` event with a `value` of `1`.

```
// contracts/GameItems.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract GameItems is ERC1155 {
    uint256 public constant GOLD = 0;
    uint256 public constant SILVER = 1;
    uint256 public constant THORS_HAMMER = 2;
    uint256 public constant SWORD = 3;
    uint256 public constant SHIELD = 4;

    constructor() public ERC1155("https://game.example/api/item/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, GOLD, 10**18, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SILVER, 10**27, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, THORS_HAMMER, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SWORD, 10**9, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SHIELD, 10**9, "");
    }
}
```

**Bonus**: what does `data` in the do in the `_mint` function?

Some contracts may pass something useful there, but typically, you can just set it to `""` or `0x`. It exists to maintain compliance with [`onERC721Received`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Receiver-onERC721Received-address-address-uint256-bytes-). The original idea (noted [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98779/how-is-the-erc721tokenreceiver-onerc721received-data-parameter-used-in-practice)) was to allow price data to be passed in this field, but very few contracts have actually implemented this (example of one that does, [here](https://github.com/sz-piotr/eth-card-game/blob/master/src/ethereum/contracts/ERC721Market.sol#L20-L31)).